# Show that if $A×B⊆C×B$, then $A⊆C$, given $B\neq ∅$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to show that if $A×B⊆C×B$, then $A⊆C$, given $B\neq ∅$. I'm struggling with coming up with an answer, because I don't know how to incorporate the cartesian product into a proof. Any help on how to start a proof will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $B \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: If $B=\varnothing$ then also $A\times B=\varnothing$ so that automatically $A\times B\subseteq C\times B$. This also if $A$ is not a subset of $C$.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Yes that's what I meant, sorry about that

Comment: It seems difficult.  But just refer to an element $(a,b)$ of $A \times B$ as an ordered pair and refer to the $a$ and $b$ component.  $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  Or in this case take $a \in A$ then any $b \in B$ gives you $(a,b) \in A\times B \subset C\times B$.  so $a \in C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a \in A$. Then for any $b \in B$, $(a,b) \in A \times B$.

Since $A \times B \subseteq C \times B$, we know $(a,b) \in C \times B$, which implies $a \in C$ and $b \in B$.

Therefore since $a \in A$ implies $a \in C$, we have $A \subseteq C$.